# Require at least one checkbox to be selected with entity field type

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony, jquery-validate

I have a many to many relationship between an entity called "clist" and another called "blast". The relationship requires that each blast contains at least one list.

I have the following code to add the entity to to my form. This is inside of the BlastType form class.

```
$builder->add('clists', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'mcBundle:Clist',
    'query_builder' => function($repo) use ($account) {
        return $repo->getClistQB($account);
    },
    'property' => 'name',
    'multiple' => TRUE,
    'expanded' => TRUE,
    'label' => 'Select List',
));
```

Which generates the following HTML.

```
<div id="blast_clists">
    <input type="checkbox" id="blast_clists_229" name="blast[clists][229]" value="229"><label for="blast_clists_229">list2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="blast_clists_231" name="blast[clists][231]" value="231"><label for="blast_clists_231">list3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="blast_clists_232" name="blast[clists][232]" value="232"><label for="blast_clists_232">list4</label>
</div>
```

If you notice, the name attribute on each of the checkboxes is different and will change depending on what lists are available. The jquery validation plugin requires that the input be identified by it's name, which is a problem.

I'm sure that this isn't a unique problem specific to me, but I have searched for every thing that I can think of with no solution in sight.

What is the correct way to require that at least one of the inputs be selected using the validator plugin?

Comment: You should be able to query for all the checkboxes under id="blast_clists"  There are several validator plugins available so I can't give you a specific line of code.

Comment: @Cerad This is the validation plugin I am using: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/